# Removing Remnants of Skype

Tags: skype, syslog, purge

Running Ubuntu 22.04 - Uninstalled Skype a few days ago using Ubuntu Software package handler.  Today my syslog file had grown to over 200gb, using all my free space.  I truncated the file and closed down the offending operations which were two skype-related operations.

Clearly, Ubuntu Software didn't manage to uninstall properly.  Now that I've cleaned up my logs, how do i find the remnants of the Skype package to purge them?  sudo apt-get purge skype returns package not found.

**--Below: added 08/16/23--**

Here is a sample of the offending lines in syslog: "Aug 14 23:00:17 arthur-OptiPlex-9020 skypeforlinux.desktop[2812]: [2812:0814/230017.695599:ERROR:address_tracker_linux.cc(355)] Failed to recv from netlink socket: Permission denied (13)"

it was just spamming this same attempt and denial log for like i'd say around 200gb.  I did manage to retain a 10gb portion as a syslog.old before i truncated the syslog.

so it's this skypeforlinux.desktop process that was causing the problem.  It hasn't started back up upon reboot thank god cause it was bogging me way down to virtual uselessness... but now I want to find those files and any other remnants of skype and purge them... this is maybe a sorta standard procedure, and perhaps i just need a link to a tutorial or a point in the right direction and i can piece it together?  I dunno, I've never needed to find phantom files before, kinda new to linux.

Comment: What was in the logs? Did you restart all the processes using the files you deleted? `man lsof fuser`